# how to display javascript error while loading .js

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you debug Javascript applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680782/how-do-you-debug-javascript-applications)

When there's a bug in my javascript .js file, no error is indicated, and the file just does not load.

Is there a fast way to debug something like this?

I have to temporarily delete half the file, test it, delete another half, test it, and so on until I isolate the problem.

How can I display the error when javascript loads the page?

Comment: Check the JavaScript console, that's all — better than going through the hassle of configuring build scripts or a linter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the firebug pluggin for firefox.

You can put break point and use the step by step debug mode.

Realy helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

- You can see if the file isn't being retrieved in the Net tab.
- You can debug it and even add breakpoints in the Script tab.
- You can view any errors/warnings in the Console tab.

Comment: or if your using chrome, even better is the inspector :) used to love firebug but the inspector in chrome is sooo much better.

Comment: Latest versions of firefox have a builtin in inspector, which I don't like as much as firebug, but no way to disable it as far as I know, and it's easy to launch wrong one.

Comment: Chrome worked right away.  Firebug did not, and I don't have time to figure it out.  Chrome wins the gold medal.  Firebug gets silver.  IE didn't even place, and actually went to Beijing instead of London by mistake.  And then crashed.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Get a js debugger for your browser: firebug if you use firefox. Chrome & Safari have builtin inspectors that do the same thing. IE as usual is more awkward. You should also check your js at jslint.com, although it gives lots of warnings you can ignore.

Answer (score -1):

- **For Firefox**: use Firebug
- **For Chrome**: use the console
- **For IE**: you're screwed. (place alert()s throughout your code and narrow down between the one that was called and the one that was not)

---

While there are many of versions of IE, this answer applies to IE 7, which is still what the majority of large corporations and government agencies use.  Sure, there are workarounds, especially if you have Visual Studio, but question did not specify a browser in the first place.

IE7 has no console, thus the users is screwed and must inject his/her JS with alert()s or use a third-party tool.

Comment: F12 is the debug console for IE, just make sure you use something like `if (console) console.log(...)` or `console&&console.log(...)`, otherwise you'll end up with lots of errors that will prevent your script from running in IE.

Comment: @zzzzBov: you are right, for newer versions.  Please see my edit.

Comment: Your information about the majority of businesses and governments is out of date.

Comment: @zzzzBov: that is wrong. I've seen two independent surveys and work with a lot of businesses and govt (US) agencies that still use IE7.  It's slowly changing, but the majority is still dependent on it.  In fact, many of them were still using IE6, until the Chinese took advantage of a Flash vulnerability a couple years ago, which affected IE6 users.  So even though IE7 has been around for a while, it's a relatively recent upgrade.

Comment: If you've seen two surveys from 3-5 years ago, they'd be accurate for that time, but they'd still be out of date. Feel free to link to a recent study to prove me wrong.

Comment: I don't have to prove you wrong, the surveys were not that long ago, and were only supplemental proof to confirm what I have personally seen.  I know from experience that this is still true and would prefer you to prove me wrong.

Comment: If you're going to make an assertion, you'd best back it up with evidence. You're making the claim that "the majority of businesses and government agencies use [IE7]", the burden of proof lies on you or your claim is no better than [Russell's teapot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_teapot). At this point you have provided no evidence whatsoever to support your claim.

Comment: @zzzzBov: As I already mentioned, I am a source, so that is all the proof I need and frankly don't really care what you say because who I've talked to, have had consultations with, and have supported is all I need for my verification (not to mention the numerous conferences that fall in the same line).  You also had made an assertion of `Your information about the majority of businesses and governments is out of date.` so the same *burden of proof* would fall on you.  I do stand corrected on one thing though, it may not be the majority of businesses, but the majority of large corporations.

Comment: This has gone on too far already. If you would like to continue to discuss this: send me an email. You are not and never will be "a source". You are also making a fallacious [appeal to experience](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority#Fallacious_appeals_to_authority).

Comment: Haha.  You are wrong on your *source* statement, as we may both be sources; whether it's credible in your eyes is not for me to determine, but my experience is enough to satiate my needs. Yes, I agree, with your last statement, but it should be "**we** are caught in a fallacious argument" as it takes at least two sides to argue.  Regardless, I hope you haven't taken any offense to any of this as sometimes I enjoy the art of the argument.  Take care, zzzzBov