# Should JavaScript be able to read element positions set in CSS through the element's style property?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

On http://jsfiddle.net/Xs9e2/ there are two elements, named ONE and TWO.  The element ONE is positioned by assigning to the style property of the DOM element using JavaScript.  The element TWO is positioned using CSS.

The HTML renders as expected.

There is a button one can press to have the `left` and `top` properties of each of the two elements alerted.  We only see the properties that were set in JavaScript, not the ones set in CSS.

What is the reason for this exactly?  *Shouldn't* we be able to read the CSS properties via JavaScript?  I may have specified something incorrectly.  I know about the "offset" properties and I know about JQuery; I'm just puzzled why this old-fashioned DOM manipulation isn't working as I would expect.  What am I missing?

Comment: [use `console.log` instead of `alert`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680782/how-do-you-debug-javascript-applications/5680785#5680785)

Comment: @zzzzBov I still get `one at ["10px","30px"]two at ["",""]` logged on the console. I am using Chrome 23.0.1271.64 on Mountain Lion if that helps.  And even if I log `two.style` to see _all_ the properties, `top` and `left` are actually there, and they are both the empty string.

Comment: The suggestion was so that you'd get better data. `console.dir(someDomNode)` in Chrome or Firefox will allow you to inspect the element's properties to see what's available.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I had to add the info about the `style` property to the comment in an edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `style` attribute is, well, an attribute. That is you can only access the values given in the HTML element's attribute `style`:

> #### [3.2.3.8 The style attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/global-attributes.html#the-style-attribute)
>
> The `style` IDL attribute must return a `CSSStyleDeclaration` whose value represents the declarations specified in the attribute. (If the attribute is absent, the object represents an empty declaration.) Mutating the `CSSStyleDeclaration` object must create a style attribute on the element (if there isn't one already) and then change its value to be a value representing the serialized form of the `CSSStyleDeclaration` object. The same object must be returned each time.

Styles given with CSS don't set the element's attribute, thus you cannot access it with `.style`.

However, you can use [getComputedStyle](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle).

Comment: I'd give you two upvotes for the w3.org references and a standards-based approach but, alas, I have only one upvote to give.

Comment: That's the *why* I was looking for, very nice! +1  I saw that the type was `CSSStyleDeclaration` in the object browser but thought there _should_ be some DOM magic to populate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IE-specific [`currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which has all styles or better standard one (as pointed out) [getComputedStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) supported in IE9+, not [`style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535870%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which reflects inline styles only.

```
alert("one at " 
    + JSON.stringify([getComputedStyle(one).left,getComputedStyle(one).top])
    + "two at "
    + JSON.stringify([getComputedStyle(two).left,getComputedStyle(two).top]));
```

Comment: Is `currentStyle` IE-specific?